# Show that graph G is not Hamiltonian

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Show that a graph G with vertex connectivity K(G) = 1 is NOT hamiltonian

How exactly can I do this?

Comment: I suspect you are overlooking the definition of $k$-vertex-connectivity, or what it means for $\kappa(G) = 1$.  Perhaps if you include this definition in your Question, a response will follow.  On the other hand, if you are asking what the definition of that is, then the Question should be edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to go about it is to suppose it *is* Hamiltonian, think about what that implies and then arrive at a contradiction.

The contradiction will be arrived at if you think about the graph's connectivity.

Here is the proof:

Let $G $ be a Hamiltonian graph such that $\operatorname{K}(G) = 1$. By definition of Hamiltonian graph, there is a cycle in $G $ containing all vertices of $G $. Because $\operatorname {K}(G) = 1$ there exists a vertex that if removed, $G $ stops being connected. Let us delete that vertex from the graph. We just made the graph disconnected. But deleting that vertex from the cycle, we destroyed the cycle and leaving a path. Therefore any other two vertices remain connected and the path was not disconnected by deleting that vertex and $\operatorname {K}(G) \not= 1$ contradicting our hypothesis. Hence we cannot have that $G $ is Hamiltonian **and** $\operatorname {K}(G) = 1$.

Comment: when it says: K(G)=1, is that the graph of just a single vertex?

Comment: @MarkRuiz nope. Saying that K(G) = 1 means that there is one edge such that removing it, will make the graph stop being connected.

Comment: and since the graph is not connected by removing said edge, there cannot be a hamiltonian path so the graph cannot be hamiltonian. But how do I write this out? I understand the concept i just don't know how to write it out

Comment: @MarkRuiz exactly. That is the main argument of the proof. I will write it out for you with the necessary formalisms

Comment: @hardmath thanks for that. Edited